# how to display value of session variable in textbox in php

Tags: php

in my project I need to take the value of selected link from one page to another page and it should be display in the textbox.

for this i have used session variable code is as below :

in caledar.php

This is not the entire script ... there is one class which generates the calendar code. below is the function.

```
function getDateLink($day, $month, $year)
        {
            // Only link the first day of every month
            $link = "";
            if ($day)
            {
                $selectedDate = $day.$month.$year;
                var_dump($selectedDate);die;
                //session_register("$selectedDate");
                //session_start();

                if (isset($_GET["selectedDate"]))
                $_SESSION['date'] = $selectedDate;

                //("location:login_sucessful.php");

                $link = "Leave_app.php";
            }
            return $link;
    }
```

in application.php

```
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" name="strt_date" value="<?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION['date'])){echo $selectedDate;}?>">
```

It is not working. also not receiving any error message.

Comment: What is not working? What is this supposed to do? If this is your entire script, you have no definitions of any of the variables on the first line.

Comment: Where are you assigning `$day`, `$month` and `$year`?

Comment: Make sure that $selectedDate contains a correct date. You can check this by putting `var_dump($selectedDate);die;` in caledar.php just after you assign `$selectedDate`

Comment: This is not the entire script ... there is one class which generates the calendar code. below is the function.

Comment: Hi Pinouchon, i used var_dump($selectedDate);die; and the output is "string(6)112012"

Answer (score 1):

You're not echoing the actual $_SESSION variable, it would need to be done like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" name="strt_date" value="<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['date'])){echo $_SESSION['date'];}?>">
```

Comment: Is the session started? You should have `session_start();` at the top of each page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: And if you echo `$selectedDate` on the first page right before you fill the session, does it definitely have data in it? (Or echo the session on the first page right after you have assigned it's data)

Comment: i used var_dump($selectedDate);die; and the output is "string(6)112012"

Comment: What happens if you echo the session variable?